# Primefaces editor is disabled after minimizing the dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have `p:editor` inside my dialog. when i minimize and restore the dialog again, the data in editor is gone and editor is disabled. Below is the xhtml code

```
<p:dialog closeOnEscape="true" responsive="true" widgetVar="dlg" id="dlg1" resizable="false" draggable="true" closable="true" dynamic="true" modal="false"  width="97%" minimizable="true" appendTo="@(body)" header="Dialog" onShow="PF('dlg').initPosition()">

<pe:ckEditor toolbar="#{config['ckEditor.toolBar']}" id="body" widgetVar="editor" readonly="false" width="100%" maxlength="50000" value="#{myBean.textVal}" />

</p:dialog>
```

i have tried both primefaces editor and primefaces ckEditor but facing same issue on both.

currently using:

- primefaces-6.1
- primefaces-extensions-6.1.1
- jsf-2.2

Edit: i have downloaded primefaces showcase and having the same issue on showcase too. Below is the code snippet.

```
 <p:dialog minimizable="true" modal="false" id="newDlg" widgetVar="dlgNew">
            <p:editor value="test"/>
 </p:dialog>
```

Screenshot1: Dialog when initial load.

[initial load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jueiE.png)

Screenshot2: Disabled dialog after minimizing and restoring on firefox

[Dialog on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMIqc.png)

Screenshot3: Disabled dialog after minimizing and restoring on chrome

[Dialog on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWBcD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, it's a primefaces defect. you can check it 
[here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3206). Hopefully it will be fixed soon.